# How to set the NumericButtonCount of the Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, datapager

I have a `DataGrid` and a `DataPager`. I am not binding the `Source` of the `Pager` to an `object` which is held in `memory` rather I am calling a `Paged` Stored Procedure that retrieves records according to the `Requested Page` by passing the `Current PageIndex` and `PageSize` to the SP in the DataPager's `PageIndexChanged` event.

```
void OnPageIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   rowIndex = (pgrProductGrids.PageIndex * pgrProductGrids.PageSize) + 1;
}
```

Now I want to set the `NumericButtonCount` for the `Pager` that would be set according to the `Count` of `Total Records` the Procedure will return. How and where do I need to set this?

I tried setting it like this to check:

```
pgrProductGrids.NumericButtonCount = 2;
```

but It Indicates one Page only and loads all the data on to it

Comment: get the count of records from either DB or from your dataset(if you are using one) then assign that to pager count.i do not see any problem here.

Comment: @shreesha Assign to which `property` thats what I am asking? I want to tell the DataPager to show the `Page Count` according to the `Total no of records` returned. Which `property` would do that?